# How to connect component output to GPIO pin in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl

I understand how to generate a PLL component in Quartus II and use it in a block diagram, but how do I connect CLKOUT to a GPIO pin in the VHDL code below?

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

ENTITY pll_test3 IS
PORT(
CLOCK_24: IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 downto 0);
RST : IN STD_LOGIC;
CLKOUT : OUT STD_LOGIC;
GPIO_0 :inout std_logic_vector(35 downto 0)
);
END pll_test3;

ARCHITECTURE MAIN OF pll_test3 IS

component PLL3 is
    port (
        clk_in_clk  : in  std_logic := 'X'; -- clk
        rst_reset   : in  std_logic := 'X'; -- reset
        clk_out_clk : out std_logic         -- clk
    );
end component PLL3;

BEGIN

C1: PLL3 PORT MAP(CLOCK_24(0),RST,CLKOUT);

---this generates error because CLKOUT is an output
GPIO_0(0) <= CLKOUT;

END MAIN;
```

Answer (score 3):

The `CLKOUT` port is mode `out`, but is used for read since in the right side
of the expression `GPIO_0(0) <= CLKOUT`, and in VHDL-2002 (and earlier) it is
illegal to read an output port.

Fix this with an internal signal from the PLL clock output, and use this signal
to drive the `CLKOUT` and `GPIO_0(0)`, with code like:

```
  signal clkout_sig : std_logic;
begin
  C1: PLL3 PORT MAP(CLOCK_24(0),RST,clkout_sig);
  CLKOUT <= clkout_sig;
  GPIO_0(0) <= clkout_sig;
```

Note that the permanent drive of `GPIO_0(0)` may give a warning from Quartus
II, since `GPIO_0` is mode `inout`, so add `'Z'` state drive to avoid the
warning

Comment: And of course, `CLKOUT <= clkout_sig;` Note that this delays CLKOUT by one delta cycle which can affect the results of simulation with poorly written testbenches.

Comment: @Brian Drummond: Fixed missing `CLKOUT <= clkout_sig;`; thanks.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you!  Is there any way to eliminate the delta cycle delay?

Comment: You can eliminate the delta cycle delay for one or the outputs, e.g. `CLKOUT`, if this is declared with mode `buffer` instead of mode `out`, since the other output can then be driven with `GPIO_0(0) <= CLKOUT`, but `GPIO_0(0)` will then be a delta cycle delay after `CLKOUT`.  However, another approach is to reconsider the test bench coding style if it is sensitive to delta cycle delay, since the test bench is then likely to be fragile.